# How To Set Up App-to-App Calling With Mutual Initiation in Sinch?

Tags: ios, swift, voip, sinch

I'm working on an iOS app that pairs callers randomly, like Chatroulette, but it seems that Sinch's iOS SDK requires one person to directly call the other.

What is the best way to generate calls (using Swift and the Sinch iOS SDK) from pairs of users without one being the "caller" and the other having to answer?

Answer (score 1):

Since Sinch doesn't keep a user database, you would just randomize that on your own user repo, and then initiate the call. When it comes to accept calls , on the incomingCall event just answer the call instead of showing an incoming call screen.